# Recursive algorithm problem(missing number)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

So I have an array A[1:n] which contains random unique numbers from 1 to n+1(including n+1). The task is to find the missing number. Usually you just make an additional array B[1:n+1] and mark each present number in array A as 1 in array B.
BUT in this problem you each number in array A is given in binary code as a string and I can access elements of A only by j-th symbol in a i-th string
The goal is to come up with an algorithm with complexity O(n)

My ideas:
I came up with a merge sort based algorithm, which would sort every string according its first number in binary code. But the complexity is O(nlgn)

Comment: Please post some code that you've written, along with input and expected output.

Comment: By array A[1:n] there is n element but 0 to n + 1 has n + 2 numbers. There will be 2 missing numbers.

Comment: Also I don't quite get what you mean by given in "binary code" as a string. Will leading zero be there or not? What is the exact format of the binary code as a string? Why can't you convert the "binary string" back to position in array B as it will still be O(n)

Comment: Let's assume `n` is a power of 2 for the moment (for the time complexity it doesn't matter if it's not). If you make a single pass through the array, checking the most significant bit of each number, can you decide if the missing number has a 0 or 1 in that position? If yes, for how many numbers do you need to check the second most significant bit? How many for the third? And so on?

Comment: @Anson Yeung, my bad, it should contain random numbers from 1 to n+1,  edited it just now

Comment: @ВасилийСлышкин can't you convert the binary code to integer in a constant time?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Anson Yeung 
1. The leading zeroes will be there, so that an input array would contain strings of the same length
2. I meant that each number will be represented as binary number(4 will be given as '100'
3. Its prohibited in the task

Comment: @AnsonYeung I was thinking the same, then just sum the values and subtract from (n+1)*(n+2)/2.

Comment: @ВасилийСлышкин Iterating through the values and converting from binary to integer should be O(n), not O(n log n).  There are languages where this is a builtin capability.

Comment: Oops, make that (n+2)*(n+3)/2 since there are (n+2) values in the range.

Comment: @Vincent van der Weele
i think i got the hint
I can make an array L that will contain all numbers that have lesser first bit than the number n//2  and an array R that will contain all numbers that have greater first bit than the number n//2. The missing number will greater than n//2 if R has more elements than L and it will be lesser than n//2 otherwise. Further i will just continue the process with an array that has a greater length.
In summary the recursive formula for time will be t(n) = t(n/2) + n or t(n) = O(n)
Do i have the right idea?

Comment: @pjs yeah i know, but i think that the goal of the problem is to come up with an algorithm that will work with O(n) on any language

Comment: @ВасилийСлышкин Even if conversion of string to binary isn't a builtin, you can easily implement it yourself (with recursion!).  Conversion time for integers should have a fixed upper bound, so it can be viewed as constant.

Comment: Yeah, that's an easier approach. Thank you

Comment: Another alternative would be to build a hash table of the values using the binary string as key, then generate the values in the range as binary and check until you find a key that is not in your hash table.  That would involve two O(n) passes, which is still O(n).

Comment: @pjs nowhere is said that n is an integer. This seems an exercise for an algorithms course, so that shortcut doesn't apply. Otherwise you could argue that the array has bounded length too (because of machine restrictions) and therefore the algorithm runs in O(1) time.

Comment: @ВасилийСлышкин exactly what I had in mind

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Since the size of the array is an integer, it follows that n is an integer.

Comment: The array values are bounded by `n`, not by machine limitations. Representing a number bounded by `n` takes `log n` bits, so the input contains `O(n log n)` bits. It is not possible to read all of those in `O(n)` time.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele If your perspective is correct, then the problem is not solvable in O(n) time since all `n log n` bits need to be read if the `n` values are in random order.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, if elements of `A` can only be accessed bit-by-bit then no `O(n)` solution is going to be possible, since all bits have to be read, and there are `log n` bits in each number. The best that can be done is `O(n log n)`.

That said, if the array contains `n` elements from the range 1 to `n+1`, with exactly one value missing, the missing value can be found by taking the sum of the array and comparing it to the sum to `n+1`, given by the standard [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), `(n+1)(n+2)/2`.

```
int n = 3;
String[] arr = {"001", "010", "100"};

int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) 
    for(int j=0, v=1; j<arr[i].length(); j++, v*=2)
        if(arr[i].charAt(j) == '1') sum += v;

int m = (n+1)*(n+2)/2 - sum;

System.out.println("Missing: " + m);
```

Output:

```
Missing: 3
```

Comment: Thanks to @pjs for pointing out that my original answer missed the detail about numbers being represented as binary strings.

Comment: This looks like Java (given the `System.out.println`), in which case I'd comment out the manual conversion (leaving it there to show the conceptual work being done) and just use `Integer`'s `parseUnsignedInt(String s, int radix)` to actually do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working implementation in Ruby using built-in binary conversion. I've commented it enough that I don't think additional verbiage is required for explanation. Notice that ordering of the binary strings is not necessary for this to work.

```ruby
ary = ["1", "010", "100", "110", "11"]  # Works with or without leading zeros
n_plus_1 = ary.size + 1
result = n_plus_1 * (n_plus_1 + 1) / 2  # Total if all values were present

# Convert each string in ary to int using base 2, and deduct from the total
ary.each { |str| result -= str.to_i(2) }

# The remainder is the missing value
puts "Missing value is #{result} (binary #{result.to_s(2)})"
```

Both that and the code below produce the following output:

> Missing value is 5 (binary 101)

If you want to avoid built-in conversion, here it is with a recursive converter which should be straightforward to translate to other languages.  Note that Ruby method arguments given a default value don't need to be provided explicitly in the method call:

```ruby
def str_to_i(char_ary, power = 1, radix = 2)
  return 0 if char_ary.size == 0  # Base case
  bit = char_ary.pop.to_i  # Remove last character in array and convert to int
  return bit * power + str_to_i(char_ary, power * radix, radix)
end

ary = ["1", "010", "100", "110", "11"]  # Works with or without leading zeros
n_plus_1 = ary.size + 1
result = n_plus_1 * (n_plus_1 + 1) / 2  # Total if all values were present

# Convert each string to array of chars, then to int, and deduct from total
ary.each { |str| result -= str_to_i(str.chars) }

# The remainder is the missing value
puts "Missing value is #{result} (binary #{result.to_s(2)})"
```

This also fulfills your use of the `recursion` tag.

If you want to do the full Monty on recursion:

```ruby
def str_to_i(char_ary, power = 1, radix = 2)
  return 0 if char_ary.size == 0  # Base case
  bit = char_ary.pop.to_i  # Remove last character in array and convert to int
  return bit * power + str_to_i(char_ary, power * radix, radix)
end

# Assuming String -> Integer can be considered O(1):
#   T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + O(1) => O(n)
# Stack size is O(log n), which should avoid stack overflow, where splitting
# array into subsets of 1 an n-1 would exceed recursive stack limits even for
# relatively small arrays (more than a few hundred).
def sum_array(ary, first = 0, last = ary.size - 1)
  # return ary[first].to_i(2) if last == first  # using built-in conversion
  return str_to_i(ary[first].chars) if last == first  # avoiding built-in
  mid = first + (last - first) / 2
  return sum_array(ary, first, mid) + sum_array(ary, mid + 1, last)
end

ary = ["1", "010", "100", "110", "11"]  # Works with or without leading zeros
n_plus_1 = ary.size + 1
result = n_plus_1 * (n_plus_1 + 1) / 2 - sum_array(ary)    

# The remainder is the missing value
puts "Missing value is #{result} (binary #{result.to_s(2)})"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that

```
XOR({1,..,4n-1})=0
```

and so, if one of the elements is missing, `XOR({1,..,4n-1}-{k})=k`,

by adding any necessary dummy elements to your given array.